# Как развернуть проект на 2х серверах (часть приложений на 1ом сервере, часть на 2ом) используя Docker Compose?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Есть у меня примерно такой `docker-compose.yml` конфиг, который на данный момент все приложения запускает на одном сервере:

```
version: '2'
services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    ports:
      - "80:80"

    volumes:
      - ./dockerfiles/nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - ../static:/static
      - ../media:/media

    depends_on:
      - web

  web:
    build: ./dockerfiles/web/
    command: bash -c 'uwsgi --ini ./settings/uwsgi_conf.ini'

    depends_on:
      - db
      - solr-docker
      - redis-docker
      - celery

    volumes:
      - ./web:/web
      - ../static:/static
      - ../media:/media

  solr-docker:
    image: solr:latest

    volumes:
      - ./dockerfiles/solr/default:/opt/solr/server/solr/mycores/default

  db:
    image: postgres:latest
```

Я хочу вынести `Solr` на 2ой сервер. После чтения статей по данному вопросу, где предлагается использовать связку `Docker Machine` + `Swarm` + `Compose`, в голове образовалась каша. Можно ли как то все сделать проще?
На SO нашел предложение использовать `extra_hosts`:

```
solr-docker:
    image: solr:latest

    volumes:
      - ./dockerfiles/solr/default:/opt/solr/server/solr/mycores/default

    extra_hosts:
      - "solrhost:111.222.333.44"
```

Но данный вариант не работает. Возможно я его не так готовлю. Может чтото нужно на 2ом сервере сделать (на котором хочу запустить `Solr`)?

`Compose` привлекает тем, что настраивается все в одном файле. Если нельзя реализовать проект на нескольких серверах через `Compose`, как это сделать максимально просто?

Comment: Одним Compose вы уже не обойдётесь, потребуется Swarm. Серьёзно подумайте, стоит ли оно того :)

Comment: Можно разбить на два docker-compose, но проще всего взять сервак помощнее. Разбить по хостам действительно логически правильнее, просто на этом этапе вас ждет большой объем ада с адаптацией к любому оркестратору.

Comment: @etki, а можно подробнее про 2 Compose? Каждый запускается на своём сервере, как я понимаю. А как при этом Solr на 2ом сервере добавить в окружение первого?

Comment: Указав айпишник второго сервера

Comment: @D-side, т.е. можно как минимум обойтись только Compose и Swarm? Из того, что я в инете находил, суцют ещё и Machine, но я не могу понять, зачем? Насколько я понимаю, Machine нужен для Мака и Винды, а у меня Линукс

Comment: @etki. Используя extra_hosts? я уже пробовал запускать 2 Compose (на втором сервере в docker-compose.yml прописывал только Solr) - не работает. Можно пример docker-compose для первого сервера, так как мой вариант, указанный выше, не работает.

Comment: Вам и extra_hosts не нужен, вы можете напрямую айпишник передать. Не забудьте только, что обращаться контейнер будет к серверу, поэтому так или иначе его нужно будет пробросить во внешний мир.

Comment: @TitanFighter `docker-machine` позволяет установить `docker` на указанную машину. если у вас уже стоит там `docker`, то она вам не нужна.